# Is there any comprehensive book or online instruction on image segmentation techniques?

Tags: remote-sensing, references, digital-image-processing, image-segmentation, image-analysis

I'm looking for a source to learn theoretical basis of image segmentation techniques thoroughly.

The desirable book, or other kinds of source you may know, should cover the techniques that are more applicable in remote sensing studies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you research academic journals and published papers. The ASPRS publishes a journal called PE&RS which may contain what you are looking for. Also the user guide to Trimble eCognition will also cover steps and techniques for segmentation and object based image analysis, which last I checked there was a free trial for eCognition.

Comment: Thank you Michael for the response. I've read some research papers you mean including  a review paper on segmentation techniques and the renown review paper on OBIA written by Blaschke, but they did not describe the concepts in detail, especially mathematical ones.

Comment: I am not aware of any comprehensive text on the subject, however OBIA originated in the medical imaging field, so you might consider widening your search to medical journals as well. Good Luck.